# AWS Athena ClientExecutionTimeoutException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am trying to do a POC for AWS Athena using Java. I am using the sample code given in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/code-samples.html

I have tried running it from eclipse and also tried creating a jar and running it on the ec2 instance using Athena IAM role.

Any help would be useful.

Thanks